# The opposite of lightning or force used as a weapon, what could it be?

Tags: weapons, lightning

**WHAT IS THE OPPOSITE OF LIGHTNING?**

If there was a sword that controls lighting, what would its elemental opposite be?

The idea is that one is positive and one is negative. One pulls electricity from the air using a positive force. I figured some magnetic force seeings that usually effects electricity would through swinging or moving it build up a charge from the friction of atoms or whatever in the air And it could either send a bolt or through contact release that energy. And the other pulls a negative force, what that force is, Idk, that is what I'm here to try and invent

Comment: So magnets? Cause magnets is the opposite side of the electromagnetic spectrum, right?

Comment: Why not use negative electric charges for your power if it's opposite relies on positive electric charges?

Comment: "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: "If a positive force weapon, that is a sword, controls lightning as its power.

What does a negative force weapon, control?"

Are you saying the sword has a magical elemental power and what would the mirror equivalent be for a "negative force"?

Comment: Yeah you pretty much summed up what I was trying to say, thats probably what I'll just put and leave it at that. @jedmeyer

Comment: Please note that the [tag:magic] tag specifically mentions you need to identify your magic system. Without that, it's impossible to identify what could be considered the opposite of "magic lightning." (Unless the opposite of a _magical elemental sword_ is a _mundane sword_.)

Comment: Which is it: light**n**ing (as in the title) or lighting (as in the body)?

Comment: The Clapper can control lighting.  CLAP ON!

Comment: "*lightning and,,, nehhh*".  Lightning is nothing but a Really Big Spark (aka flow of electrons).  The opposite of the flow of electrons is... **not the flow of electrons** (aka an insulator).  Since our muscles, including the heart, need electrons to flow, a magic wooden (good insulator) Sword would kill you by preventing electrons from flowing.  You'd just collapse dead.

Comment: Fighting someone with an antimatter sword would be like crossing the streams. The opposite of an antimatter sword is just a regular sword. If there was a take-away from that discussion I would've hoped it be this: "You could get something done with the controlling of particles in terms of causing Cold. Temperature is just the vibration and/or movement of atoms/molecules. One other approach is to have your opposite day sword just pull energy from the object in question." - *Matter is merely energy condensed to a slow vibration.*

Comment: In [Final Fantasy](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Lightning_(element)) it's Water. Lighting "forms a trifecta with Fire and Ice", while Water kinda does its own thing, being introduced only after the trifecta is well established. "It is usually the opposing element of Water, but occasionally it can be the opposing element of Poison and Ice." Lighting, Fire, Ice, and Water.

Comment: Are you asking for the opposite of ejecting,  ie positrons?

Comment: This is in the reopen queue, but I'm not sure it's ready.  Electricity (in all its forms) can be thought of (at least, weaponized) as the addition of electrons where naturally there wouldn't be any.  What's the opposite?  The addition of protons?  The removal of electrons? Grounding?  I'd recommend walking away from this question and re-asking it in our [sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) where we can help you refine it into an SE-appropriate question (one-specific-question/one-best-answer).

Comment: Note on your edit: photons are the antiparticles of themselves. There is nothing like "dark light"

Comment: Does the sword control lightning (trigger, aim) or does it create lighning (from the tip, or from anywhere?) Or both?.  I.e. what ecactly are the powers of this sword?

Comment: @bukwyrm The idea is that one is positive and one is negative. One pulls electricity from the air using a positive force. I figured some magnetic force seeings that usually effects electricity would through swinging or moving it build up a charge from the friction of atoms or whatever in the air. And the other pulls a negative force, what that force is, Idk, that is what I'm here to try and invent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're looking for the opposite of a **positive** force, you're misinterpreting what *exactly* a Force is.

A Force is what's known as a **vector:** it is a value that has both a **quantity** and a **direction**. In most cases, the quantity is Newtons (a unit of force) and ANY prescribed direction (right, left, down, up, etc.)

A Force is *positive* if it acts toward the prescribed direction and is *negative* if acts in the opposite direction.

Consider the following:

[image]

If we consider "Up" as positive Force, then the pull of the rope is a *positive* force acting on the climber. Therefore, the pull of gravity is a *negative* force acting on the climber.

The idea of a "negative" force is about perspective.

Now let's assume you mean force in an abstract way:

[Lightning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning) is actually not a force itself, but the rapid movement of electrons to a electron deficient space. Simply put, it moves so fast that it releases immense amounts of energy, causing the shockwaves we call "thunder".

There are a couple ways you could conceive of an opposite of lightning.

- Lightning, but in the opposite direction would have a similar Physical Effect, but on the receiving end of the bolt. That may not be ideal for stereotypical damage, but since its magic, perhaps you just drained all the electrons from the victim suddenly? That could be fatal with a little hand waving.
- Protons, the opposite charged particles of electrons, could instead be drawn to your weapon. Since Protons are fundamental particles in atoms: you get a flash of lightning, and BOOM. The person has vanished in atomic particles. In Physics, this is basically impossible, due to some [more complex forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_interaction), but since you're using a magic system, it is at least rooted in duality.

Comment: Well I guess I'm at a loss, if it is the rapid movement of electrons then I guess nothing else could really do that but lightning itself... Although would a the controlling of particles be able to cool down and freeze something?

Comment: Let's move this into the Chat (https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82157/discussion-of-the-opposite-of-lightning)

Comment: "Since Protons are fundamental particles in atoms" is wrong. Protons are made of quarks.

Comment: "Draining all the electrons from the victim..." - this would not just end the victim, but a good chunk of the world as well.

Comment: That was a simplification and a matter of semantics. Not going to try to explain the fundamental particles on S.E. when I can't even explain them to myself.

Answer (score 4):

You really do get to choose your own opposites, because you get to assign your own meanings.  However, I would feel comfortable choosing "earth" as an opposite.

My logic would be to bring in the duality of electricity.  You can't have electricity flow from a source without a sink to flow into.  If you think of the clouds as the source of lightning, then the Earth is always the sink.  (Actual lightning is [more complicated](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oI9Af3eiddI)!)

The "negative" of a lightning strike would be something that, no matter how much you struck it with lightning, it simply didn't care.  Earth tends to meet those criteria.

Answer (score 3):

Let me see if I understand properly: You need the opposite of a sword that controls lightning. Soo... let's start analyzing your weapon:

- Sword is a physical weapon. And it punctures and cuts through a physical interaction with the target (going through the chest of someone, for example).
- Lightning produces a huge amount of heat and lots of light.

So: Let's think in the contrary:

The opposite of heat: **cold**.  Your weapon must subtract energy from the target (freeze it). And luckily for your question, the coldest temperature can be obtained by non-physical means (opposite to the sword). You can achieve freezing temperatures with light (lasers).
So, the opposite will be a non-physical weapon (lasers) that freeze the target to death (almost absolute zero) by means of the interaction of the absorbed and emitted photons.
I will skip the technical details here, but you can find more information on this page:
[Scientific American: How are temperatures close to absolute zero achieved and measured?](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/how-are-temperatures-clos/)

Comment: Do you think the weapon could absorb or make the atoms stationary. The article mentioned scattering atoms and cooling them down with lasers, but do you think a charged weapon could do this without lots of lazer beams. is there anything you could recommend that could absorbs heat and makes a cold environment around it.

Comment: @WolvesEyes, you are right about that. Lots of lasers are impractical to handle around like a sword. So, if you want something more portable, you could try making a "frost gun" with a refrigerating gas. You can see an example in this youtube video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y8CdgZhnHdE

Comment: There is energy and there is the lack of energy; hot and cold, respectively. +1

Answer (score 0):

A magnetic shield.

It's the one thing that can redirect lightning, plus magnets and electicity are inherently linked. Plus the shield works as an opposite for the sword as well.